# JAVA: Custom Format for Current Date in Java?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I want to achieve the below format using Simple Date Format:

**July 13, 2016**

I have used the below code but i dont know  the format to use:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss");
Date currentDate = new Date();
String currentDateString = dateFormat.format(currentDate);
try { 
    currentDate = dateFormat.parse(currentDateString);
} catch (ParseException e) {

}
```

Please guide.

Comment: Read the  javadoc of SimpleDateFormat and find out what the format is

Comment: I didnt find though.. Will this work : "MMM dd, ''yyyy"

Comment: @Shirish you should use MMMM dd,yyyy

Comment: See API documentation of [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (<= click the link)

Comment: If you were expecting a `Date` object with a certain format, then that's not going to work. A `Date` object does not have a format. You cannot get a `Date` object that knows by itself to print in a certain format; the `Date` object does not remember its format.

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting. This topic has been addressed many hundreds of times already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the date format `'MMMM dd, yyyy'`

Sample code:

```
package problems.outputDateAsFormatX;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateOutput {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        String currentDateString = dateFormat.format(currentDate);
        System.out.println("My date is: " + currentDateString);
    }
}
```

Output:

> My date is: ***July 04, 2016***

The format was derived from the [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) documentation.

The "dd" and "yyyy" bit are pretty standard, you might want to pay particular attention to the month bit.

> **Month**: If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is
>   interpreted as text; otherwise, it is interpreted as a number.

So 'MMM' would have given you the shortform "Jul", adding an additional "M" resolves to **July**.

Answer (score 1):

MMM - For the month in the year as Text
dd - For the day month as numner
yyyy - For the year as number

So that makes:
MMM dd, yyyy

I dind't tried it but it should work, please give me a short feedback if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

you need to parse "MMMM dd,yyyy"

```
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd,yyyy");
         Date currentDate = new Date();
         String currentDateString = dateFormat.format(currentDate);
         System.out.println(currentDateString);
         try { 
             currentDate = dateFormat.parse(currentDateString);

         } catch (ParseException e) {

         }

          }
```

[**OUTPUT**](https://ideone.com/QxoagM)

Comment: @downvoter care to comment

Comment: The question has to do with formatting a date, not with parsing a date. Formatting = converting a date to a string, parsing = converting a string to a date.

Comment: @Jesper I dont know if you are the downvoter but how is my answer different from that of the accepted answer